# how to get type of auto variable in C++

Tags: c++, types, auto

I want gets the type of the auto variable and forces another variable become this type,i don't know whether  c++ has such feature or function.

Comment: Declytpe or use Auto again?

Comment: `decltype` might help you.

Comment: See Decltype...

Comment: What's up with this question? +5 for a dupe question, +10 for a very trivial dupe answer..?

Comment: @SergeyA We're welcoming

Comment: @SergeyA, those who voted for your comment, downvoted the post.

Comment: @codekaizer I generally would not downvote a harmless dupe just for being a dupe, but when it is upvoted for no reason, I understand people might want to balance it slightly, only to make sure we are sending right signals to other users. Also this is not a well-asked question even if it would not be a dupe.

Comment: The [policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361399/is-it-fine-to-vote-up-down-to-compensate-the-votes-of-others) is "don't vote based on the current score". Although I do think that the voting is weird, unless a voting ring is involved there should be no problem.

Comment: @SergeyA This question is exactly what I typed in google and the answer exactly provided me with what I needed. Simple solution for simple problem, which I am too lazy to investigate further - works for me.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

```
auto a = 42;
decltype(a) b;
```